# Matplotlib. The scroll bar doesn't exist?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some Python and `matplotlib` library questions.

[image]

**First:**

I want to remove the text in the bottom left corner (axex: x,y and the coords).

**Second:**

Can I set a scroll bar on the chart?

I want a fixed width chart where a horizontal scroll bar appears if the data is too large to fit in the fixed width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a scroll bar with

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 12))
axframe = plt.axes([0.125, 0.1, 0.775, 0.03])
sframe = Slider(axframe, 'Point-Nr', 1, 200, valinit=1, valfmt='Nr.%d')


def update(val):
    ax.plot(int(sframe.val), int(sframe.val)*2, 'o-')

sframe.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

Regards
Dr. Cobra

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But i'd like to know one more thing:
Can i hide this annotation on this slider?
[link](https://yadi.sk/i/oZ60kNiqxiutf)
If yes - how can i do this? )

Comment: You can introspect modules for yourself and find the right answer with

Comment: print dir(sframe.valtext)

Comment: so it`s clear to hide the value with sframe.valtext.set_visible(False)